# jQuery changing an image on hover, then maintain image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

I'm at a bit of a problem with jQuery and an image.

I'm trying to create a simple system where an image changes on hover (which I've successfully made work with jQuery .hover()) however I'm now trying to set it up so if the user clicks on the image, the source is permanently changed to the hover image.

The problem I'm having is when I click, the source changes but when I hover off it changes back to the "off" image! Such a simple problem but I can't find a solution.

The hover code:

```
$("#image").hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", getImageSourceOn("image"));
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", getImageSourceOff("image"));
});
```

The functions getImageSourceOn / Off simply return a string based on the parameter with the new source.

The onClick code:

```
var imageSource = $(imageID).attr("src");
  var onOff = imageSource.substring((imageSource.length - 5), (imageSource.length - 4));
  if (onOff == "F")
  {
    //alert("Off\nstrID = " + strID);
    $(imageID).attr("src", getImageSourceOn(strID));
  }
  else
  {
    //alert("On");
    $(imageID).attr("src", getImageSourceOff(strID));
  }
```

This code just takes the source and looks for On / Off within the source to put the opposite as the image. I tried using .toggle() instead of this substring method but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I would suggest to use Background-Image css property and just change the Background-Image-Position because changing the src attribute will not display until the image is downloaded and so for the first time on hover it will not display changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a global variable. Attach a function on the `click` event:

```
var clicked = false;

$("#image").click(function(){
  if(!clicked)
    clicked = true;
  else
    $(this).attr("src", getImageSourceOff("image"));
});
```

Then modify you `hover` code

```
  $("#image").hover(function () {
      $(this).attr("src", getImageSourceOn("image"));
  }, function () {
     if(!clicked)
       $(this).attr("src", getImageSourceOff("image"));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks very much Rolando. With this system, the image stays the same when clicked. However, I'd like the image to back when clicked again.

Comment: Thanks Rolando. How could I adapt the code to make it re-useable? At the moment it works for one click on and off but not any further ones.

Comment: Sorted, I added 'clicked = false;' to the image click function else statement.

Comment: If you want to have support for multiple images, you might want to simply add a class to the clicked image. Something like:`$(this).addClass("clicked")` in place of `clicked = true` and then use `if(!$(this).hasClass("clicked"))` in place of `if(!clicked)`